# rj not installing for eclipse/R Statet

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

I realize there are several posts on this, so apologies if I'm breaching etiquette. In my case, I've tried several of them, and I just can't seem to get the rj issue (of having it installed properly) resolved.

I tried the CMD INSTALL recommendation and literally copied the tar file to my R executable directory

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-test-load rj_*.tar.gz
```

I used a DOS cmd window to run it, and it failed using the * notation, so I substituted the exact rj tar file name by navigating to the path...
C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\bin\x64\rj_0.5.0-5.tar.gz
and running

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-test-load rj_0.5.0-5.tar.gz
```

This seemed to work as R shows all Java packages installed (inc. Rjava)

```
> ("rj" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])
[1] TRUE
> ("rJava" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])
[1] TRUE
>
```

Yet, in the eclipse environment, I'm still getting rj missing error.
Any thoughts on what to try next? I really want to get the debug capability to work here and pulling my hair out over this.

Oh, and also even though it shows installed in R. If I try to launch inside R, I get:

```
> library(rj)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rj', details:
  call: .jcall("de/walware/rj/server/RJ", "Lde/walware/rj/server/RJ;", 
  error: RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rj'
```

[image]

> 

- Using Eclipse SDK Version: 3.8.0
  StatET 3.01.02
  rj_0.5.0-5

Comment: Which version of `rj` are you installing? CRAN or the StatET version? you need the StatET version.

Comment: Downloaded from http://www.walware.de/goto/statet. rj-0.5.0-5 Although, come to think of it, it is an older (stable) version. Would the version have anything to do with it? Should I reinstall newer version?

Comment: Ahah, that reminds me... the screenshots indicate that you are running win 64-bit. You have to make sure you have 64-bit all the way in the stack, i.e. OS, R, java and eclipse.  Your problem is most likely that you haven't installed 64-bit java.

Comment: PS. As long as your version of StatET, Eclipse and rj match, it shouldn't matter that you are running an older version.

Comment: So I did have older version of java and reinstalled the 64-bit java. Unfortunately, I had popup window to allow/disallow private/public connection to java (which I declined). Error box (above) is still present. Did I mess up by not allowing java access through firewall?

Comment: well I tried installing newer version of rj and rgd and R says it can't delete old version.

Comment: Any luck with `install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")`?

Comment: No. s()[,"Package"])
[1] FALSE
> install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:\Users\owner\Documents/R/win-library/2.12’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1/bin/windows/contrib/2.12
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  packages ‘rj’, ‘rj.gd’ are not available

Comment: Also, [this page](http://www.walware.de/it/statet/installation.mframe) suggests that StatET 3.0 (and the current 3.1) is compatible with R 2.13 and above, but not R 2.12. Perhaps upgrading R to 2.15 or downgrading StatET to 2.0 and RJ to 1.0 will help.

Comment: I was going to try that one. I just get worried about re-installing R, etc.. because if I can't get it to work, I may have other problems with R.

Comment: @pat On Windows, it is easy to concurrently install multiple versions of R. They will be installed by default to `C:\Program Files\R-2.xx.y`.